# Cleaning up with IDisposable issues

Tags: c#, regex, idisposable, ienumerator, dispose

I am trying to call these functions to get rid of stuff I don't need, but my code seems to be defeating me in what I am begining to perceive to be a vain struggle. I have tried multiple ways to solve these last two errors, but the IEnumerator is giving me wild cards. errors are on the lines :
 if (enumerator2 is IDisposable) 
and 
 if (enumerator is IDisposable)

```
        try
        {
            enumerator = matchs.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                IEnumerator enumerator2;
                Match current = (Match) enumerator.Current;
                num = 0;
                try
                {
                    enumerator2 = current.Groups.GetEnumerator();
                    while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
                    {
                        Group group = (Group) enumerator2.Current;
                        strArray[num, num3] = group.Value;
                        num++;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (enumerator2 is IDisposable)
                    {
                        (enumerator2 as IDisposable).Dispose();
                    }
                }
                if (num2 < num3)
                {
                    num2 = num3;
                }
                num3++;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (enumerator is IDisposable)
            {
                (enumerator as IDisposable).Dispose();
            }
        }
        strArray[num, 0] = Conversions.ToString((int) (num2 + 1));
        return strArray;
    }
```

Edit- Specific error messages:
Use of unassigned local variable 'enumerator2'
Use of unassigned local variable 'enumerator'

Comment: You need to post the specific error messages

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the enumerators directly rather than using the more idiomatic `foreach` loop? Also, look into the `using` statement.

Comment: The line `(enumerator2 as IDisposable).Dispose();` can be a problem. It basically means "Call Dispose on enumerator2 if it is disposable. Otherwise call Dispose on null". If you use the correct syntax, `((IDisposable)enumerator2).Dispose()`, your tools will be happier.

Comment: The generic version of `IEnumerator` inherits from `IDisposable`, so it will make your code simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `foreach` loop as pointed out by others.

*But*, the reason you are getting that error is because when `enumerator2` is used in the `finally` block, the compiler cannot know that it gets set to some value (because it may not be in some exceptional situations). You can fix your code as-is, by doing:

```
IEnumerator enumerator2 = null;
Match current = ...
```

Comment: This was the exact answer I needed for this question, even if its not the most effective way to do it, ty.

Answer (score 5):

Use a for-each loop instead of a while loop. It will call Dispose for you if needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257(VS.71).aspx